# Attaching event listener to nested element

Tags: jquery, html

I have an editor that has a toolbar that pops up when I highlight text. I want to do something when the user clicks on any of the buttons on the toolbar but my jquery uses a variable as a selector. What is the correct syntax for this?

**HTML:**

```
<div>
  <div class="toolbar">
    <button class="bold"></button>
    <button class="italics"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jquery:**

```
$('#' + this.editorId > 'toolbar' > button).on("click", (event) => {
  console.log("button on toolbar clicked")
})
```

Comment: Hard to say... since the context is unclear... But the concatenation you expose is incorrect. Try `$('#' + this.editorId +'>.toolbar>button').` The selector operands have to be IN the selector's string. And `toolbar` is a class...

Comment: Now where `this` is defined in your code? And are you sure the element having an `editorId` attribute is the immediate parent of `.toolbar`?

Comment: if `.toolbar` is not the direct child of the editor, do I need to chain all the children in between? Is there a way to identify the buttons within the toolbar that's within the editor?

Comment: From the editor, you can use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/). But you can do it from an existing element only...

Comment: You should post more markup and tell what editor you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume that `this.editorId` is the direct ancestor of `.toolbar`, ie,

```
<div id="toolbar-container">
  <div class="toolbar">
    <button class="bold"></button>
    <button class="italics"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

then, if `this` is the context of the enclosing scope, like, for example

```
function () {
  this.editorId = document.getElementById("#toolbar-container");

  $('#' + this.editorId + ' > .toolbar > button')
      .on("click", (event) => { 
           console.log("button on toolbar clicked") 
      });
}
```

Now if `.toolbar` is not a direct descendant of `editorId`, then we can use `$.find()`, and our `handler` would be:

```
$('#' + this.editorId + ' .toolbar > button')
      .on("click", (event) => { 
           console.log("button on toolbar clicked") 
      });
```

Where I removed the `>` between `this.editorId` and `.toolbar`.

Comment: Not at all, @LouysPatriceBessette, arrow functions take context from the immediate scope. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this

Comment: Yes... But how can you assume anything about the syntax used when OP asks about the correct syntax to use?

Comment: Plus, @LouysPatriceBessette, I'm assuming that the OP has a reference to the eidtor `id`. I don't really care how it got into the handler's context. My answer was just an attempt at completeness.

Comment: Answering too fast often lead to downvotes... I didn't... But I think you run after it.

Comment: `this.editorId` is just a reference to a value in my vue component. I was unsure of how to write the proper syntax using jquery when I have a variable as my selector. I should have clarified more in my question. Sorry for any confusion. But thank you both for your help, you're both correct and I've solved my issue. Thanks!

Comment: Very kind of you not to downvote a well formed answer, @louyspatricebessette. Thank you for the sage advice.

Comment: I couln'd downvote since you were posting about everything I was saying in comment... My point here is we did had enought information, from my point of view and experience, to answer correctly yet. That's all.